# JQuery Append Unexpected Token "<"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using $.ajax to get content from a .php page which returns something similar to the following

```
<div class="item">
   <h1>Item Name</h1>
   <div class="content">
      <p>Content here</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my fetching code:

```
$.ajax(
{
   type: "GET",
   url: appletGet,
   data:
   {
      'name': this.name
    },
    success: function (data) 
    { 
       console.log(data.replace('\n', ''));
       $(element).append(data.replace('\n', ''));
    }
});
```

and I try to append it using

```
$(element).append(data);
```

but I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I look at some other posts and they all talked about the new lines causing the issue. Because of that, I attempted to remove new lines.

```
$(element).append(data.replace('\n', ''));
```

Which did not work. So, how do I go about fixing this?

**Edit:** Kepi gave an answer earlier which proposed that I use

```
$.parseHTML(data)
```

and then append that. He/She removed his/her answer due to second-guessing himself/herself. Since I do not think you can give credit when it is removed (I am correct right?) I am putting this solution here for future reference.

Kepi! Come get your credit!

Comment: There is typo error </P> should be </p>

Comment: @ManishShukla that is fine .. though it is not recommended

Comment: HTML can be either upper, lower or mixed case, it's not a typo (unless it's XHTML, where it has to be lowercase).

Comment: @UioShi I recommend making that line in your code multiple lines to have a easier debugging process. e.g. `$(element)`break`.append(`break`data.replace(`break`'\n', ''`break`)`break`);` Then see which line has the problem

Comment: can you post the code responsable for fetching the data? (the ajax call)

Comment: Which line? If you refer to me trying to remove the new lines, it was just so the error would go away according to the posts I read; that is since new lines cause the error I posed.

Comment: @UioShi I meant the code, so you might see where the problem originates.

Comment: Works just fine: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j19n4m3r/).

Comment: How does the data look like?

Comment: Print `data` in your browser console before appending, and see what it gives. From the code you posted there's nothing wrong.

Comment: @UioShi There's no problem with newlines in HTML data.

Comment: k, this is just a guess, but maybe you are expecting a json back and there is a parsing issue, you should check the `dataType` for `$.ajax`

Comment: Hey guys! Don't hit on @Kepi, I did what he said and it actually got rid of the error and everything is working perfectly!

Comment: `dataType : 'html'`  should do the trick.

Comment: I want to give @Kepi credit, but his answer is no longer there. He proposed using $.parseHTML(data) which worked 100% for me. D:

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong here. Refer to this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fu4mmr1r/1/):

```
var data = '<div class="item">'+
   '<h1>Item Name</h1>'+
   '<div class="content">'+
      '<p>Content here</p>'+
   '</div>'+
'</div>';

$("body").append(data.replace("\n", ""));
```

Moreover if you are getting html response you may consider using `$.load`.

Comment: If you don't see anything wrong, how is this a solution? It should be a comment.

Comment: Moreover, what for `.replace("\n", "")` is there?

Comment: I don't know why he tried to replace the `\n`s.

@UioShi I need to see your code for ajax call and the actual response you are getting.